# Print elements of a ternary tree

Tags: java

**A full ternary tree with depth n is given. Write a program that prints all nodes of the tree in Pre-Order. Enumeration starts from 0 and goes sequentially through the levels.**

**Input:** n is the depth of the tree.

**Output:** a sequence of nodes in Pre-Order divided by spaces.

**Sample Input:**
*2*

**Sample Output:**
*0 1 4 5 6 2 7 8 9 3 10 11 12*

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int targetDepth = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int currentDepth = 1;
    int node = 0;
    System.out.print(node + " ");
    printNodes(node, currentDepth, targetDepth);
}

public static void printNodes(int node, int currentDepth, int targetDepth) {
    if (targetDepth == 1) {
        System.out.print((3 * node + 1) + " " + (3 * node + 2) + " " + (3 * node + 3));
        return;
    }
    if (currentDepth < targetDepth) {
        int leftChild, midChild, rightChild;
        int rightParent = 3 * node + 3;
        node++;
        while (node <= rightParent) {
            leftChild = 3 * node + 1;
            midChild = 3 * node + 2;
            rightChild = 3 * node + 3;
            System.out.print(node + " " + leftChild + " " + midChild + " " + rightChild + " ");
            node++;
        }
        node = rightParent;
        currentDepth++;
        printNodes(node, currentDepth, targetDepth);
    }
}
```

A simple test reports an error: Invalid answer. The test uses a tree with a depth of 3, although the test passes successfully with a tree depth of 2. I have already checked 100 times, based on the conditions of the problem, the answer must be correct. Perhaps I am missing something. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what u need to do is:

```
public static void process(Node n){
  sysout(n.value)
  process(n.right)
  process(n.mid)
  process(n.left)}
```

what you are doing is:

```
public static void process(Node n){
      sysout(n.value)
      sysout(n.left.value)
      sysout(n.mid.value)
      sysout(n.right.value)
      process(n.right)}
```

keep it simple, just try to print current node and then move on to its children.

If you are currently getting a course on data structures, there is also a method that uses stack or queue. I recommend checking on it too. While using recursion, you naturally use the process stack java uses.

pseudo code goes like:

```
push initial node into the stack 
while stack has nodes:
     pop node from the stack 
     print nodes value 
     if node is not at the target depth:
          push node's children onto the stack(from right to left)
```

when stack is empty, you got your sequence!

Comment: Yes, indeed, it was required to display the elements of each of the tree branches from top to bottom, and not in turn. It wasn't very clear from one example, but your solution helped me figure it out. thanks